# Connect to a wireless miracast display using Windows API

Tags: windows, winapi, multiple-monitors, miracast

I would like to connect to a wireless miracast display which is already paired with the host. I am able to use [`EnumDisplayDevices`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162609(v=vs.85).aspx) to list the wireless display device. I have tried to use [`ChangeDisplaySettingsEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413(v=vs.85).aspx) but it didn't work, I used `CDS_SET_PRIMARY` on the miracast display device hoping that it would automatically connect to it and set it as the primary display.

It looks like `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx` cannot establish a connection on it's own. There should be some kind of API which can connect to the display. I have also tried [`SetDisplayConfig`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff569533(v=vs.85).aspx) with `SDC_TOPOLOGY_CLONE` to change the display configuration to "clone" thinking that it would automatically connect to the display.

**Question:** What is the proper way to connect to a wireless display device using Windows API?

Comment: [`StartMiracastSession`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn265504(v=vs.85).aspx) looks promising but it is a driver function which cannot be called from the outside.